# Error in quantile.default(samples.gamma, c(0.5, 0.025, 0.975)) : missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

Tags: r, autoregressive-models

I have tried my best but seems I just don't understand what to do and need help.
I'am running a conditional auto-regressive model. Here is my code:

`model2 <- ST.CARar(formula = formula, family = "poisson", data = malaria, W = W, burnin = 20000, n.sample = 220000, thin = 10)`

```
Setting up the model
Generating 20000 post burnin and thinned (if requested) samples
 ========================================================================| 100%
Summarising results
```

> Error in quantile.default(samples.gamma, c(0.5, 0.025, 0.975)) :
>   missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

I don't mind providing more information or data, but I need the help.

Comment: Error clearly shows you have `NA` or `NaN` values in data.

Comment: what happens if you run the function with `data = na.omit(malaria)`?

Comment: I have tried using: data = na.omit(malaria), same error shows up as earlier. I have also tried is.na(malaria) all was FALSE